# Is _1 part of C++0x?

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, c++11

I've seen [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4008369) recent [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009530) using `_1` as a pure C++0x solution (no explicit mention of boost lambdas).

Is there such an animal as `std::_1` I would think that having native lambdas will make such a construct redundant.

A Google code search for `std::_1` brings [two results](http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=std%3A%3A_1&hl=en) from the same project so that's inconclusive.

Comment: do you think they would be in namespace std? In boost they are in the global namespace...

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982158.aspx) has `_1` in a `std::placeholders` namespace and both your linked answers refer to that as well. This isn't conclusive either, but if nothing else you may be searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: Oh, just found that they are in [TR1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1836.pdf)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, they are part of C++0x inside the `std::placeholders` namespace, from the latest draft (n3126) §20.8.10.1.3 "Placeholders":

```
namespace std {
   namespace placeholders {
      // M is the implementation-defined number of placeholders
      extern unspecified _1;
      extern unspecified _2;
        .
        .
        .
      extern unspecified _M;
   }
}
```

They are actually [included in TR1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1#Function_object_binders) ([n1836](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1836.pdf) §3.6.4; [n1455](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1455.htm)) along with `bind`, which are taken from the [Boost.Bind library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/bind/bind.html).

Answer (score 5):

Apparently they are part of C++ 0x and should be defined in the `<functional>` header in a conformant compiler, see the following FAQ:

[C++ 0x FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are part of C++0x. I haven't double-checked the TR1 specs, but I suspect they were added there (TR1 was essentially a library-only extension to C++03, so it couldn't rely on lambdas), and then, since it's already there in TR1, it'd be needlessly disruptive to remove it again in C++0x, even though it's no longer really necessary once you have true lambdas.

Comment: Placeholders are still necessary as C++0x lambdas aren't polymorphic.

Comment: They are in <tr1/functional>.  They were added with bind and other things.