# What does "cout <<(_1*3)" mean?

Tags: c++, boost, cout

I found a simple code:

```
using namespace boost::lambda;
typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;
std::for_each(
    in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
```

and I found `_1` is used to represent each input integer, but how does this `_1` work? Anyone knows?

PS: 
This code is from the first example of BOOST. When I ran the file, I found the for_each will never terminate and it kept read numbers after each "return" click. Any idea why this happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a [placeholder](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders) (also look at [this SO question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009838/is-1-part-of-c0x):

The `std::placeholders` namespace contains the placeholder objects `[_1, . . . _N]` where N is an implementation defined maximum number.

When used as an argument in a `std::bind` expression, the placeholder objects are stored in the generated function object, and when that function object is invoked with unbound arguments, each placeholder _N is replaced by the corresponding Nth unbound argument.

The types of the placeholder objects are `DefaultConstructible` and `CopyConstructible`, their default copy/move constructors do not throw exceptions, and for any placeholder `_N`, the type `std::is_placeholder<decltype(_N)>` is defined and is derived from `std::integral_constant<int, N>`.

Comment: This isn't a standard library placeholder. This placeholder was/is used by Boost.Lambda to create lambdas before they were added to the language in C++11.

Comment: @Simple, true, but I didn't know the OP was using boost when I was answering:P The other answer contains links to boost docs, though.

Answer (score 4):

Lambda to multiply each number by three. After reading from `stdin`. `in` should be an iterator - paste full code please.

`_1` is a placeholder as explained in the other answer. The question should have been tagged `Boost` as well. That is a [Boost.Lambda](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/lambda.html).

[Lambda expressions in details](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html)