# How can I explicitly instantiate a variadic template so the template types are constructed and tied into one callable?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I've made use of interesting composition components like this one:

[callable composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829106/functional-composition-with-variadic-templates-in-c11)

And I've successfully used this in a context where I dynamically instantiate various objects, and call a virtual function on them `getCallable()` which returns a `std::bind` of to a member function. I then use the composition concept in the link above with the operator `*` to compose all of them into one callable. This works fine and with a single function call I get a long chain of member function calls to my objects. I'm trying to achieve something similar but at compile time when I know what my call chain should be (two object A's followed by a B, say). Something like this:

```
template <class T...>
struct CallChain
{
    static ?someComposedType? get();
};
```

I want to have a few variations of fully static const structs like this:

```
struct ArgStructX
{
    static const int x = 8;
    static const bool y = false;
    static const float z = 17.6;
};
```

And a few callable classes like this:

```
struct CallableX
{
    CallableX(const ArgStructX&);
    void operator()();
};
```

And then I want to be able to say something like this (for example):

```
template class CallChain<CallableX, ArgStructX, CallableY, ArgStructY>; //explicit instantiate in some C file

typedef template CallChain<CallableX, ArgStructX, CallableY, ArgStructY> MyChain;
auto F = MyChain::get();
```

What I'm trying to achieve at the last line above is for that to create a `CallableX` by passing it an `ArgStructX`, a `CallableY` by passing it an `ArgStructY`, and then internally compose them (as per the link above, for example) and give me back the final callable. So then if I said `F()` it would be `CallableY(CallableX())`. If done compile time, there should be no indirection (as opposed to my dynamic approach) in the final call chain. How could I go about this?

Comment: How do you expect to compose anything when your example `CallableX` class returns `void`?