# Self-composing a function with changing deduced template value

Tags: c++, function, composition

How to carry out self_composeN(func)(x) if func has a deduced template value that needs to be changed every time?  What is an example of this?  Here I've written rotate_tuple which rotates all the components of a given tuple to the left by N.  I want to apply it multiple times (I know that I can just multiply N by whatever to achieve this, but I want to know the generic solution to this, because there will be other such functions that will not have such a short cut).  Here is my code for rotate_tuple, which has been thoroughly tested (and it extracts the resulting type too).  You need not worry about the details, I don't think, except maybe for struct rotate_tuple itself, which is quite short.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

template <int NUM_LEFT, int SHIFT>
class rotate_tuple_helper {
    private:
        static constexpr int positiveModulo (int i, int n) {return (i % n + n) % n;}
        template <typename TUPLE>
        static constexpr int shift() {return positiveModulo (SHIFT, std::tuple_size<TUPLE>::value);}
    public:
        template <typename TUPLE>
        auto operator() (const TUPLE& t) const -> decltype (std::tuple_cat (std::make_tuple (std::get<shift<TUPLE>()>(t)), rotate_tuple_helper<NUM_LEFT-1, SHIFT+1>()(t))) {    
            return std::tuple_cat (std::make_tuple (std::get<shift<TUPLE>()>(t)), rotate_tuple_helper<NUM_LEFT-1, SHIFT+1>()(t));
        }
};

template <int SHIFT>
class rotate_tuple_helper<0, SHIFT> {
    public:
        template <typename TUPLE>
        std::tuple<> operator() (const TUPLE& t) const {return std::tuple<>();} 
};

template <typename TUPLE, int SHIFT>
struct rotate_tuple_type {
    using type = decltype (rotate_tuple_helper<std::tuple_size<TUPLE>::value, SHIFT>()(std::declval<TUPLE>()));
};

template <int SHIFT>
struct rotate_tuple {
    template <typename TUPLE>
    typename rotate_tuple_type<TUPLE, SHIFT>::type operator() (const TUPLE& t) const {
        return rotate_tuple_helper<std::tuple_size<TUPLE>::value, SHIFT>()(t);
    }
};

int main() {
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<int, std::string, double, char, std::string, int, double, char>;
    const tuple_type t (8, "house", 3.14, 'b', "apple", 6, 1.5, '!');
    using rotate_tuple_type = rotate_tuple_type<tuple_type, 3>::type;
    const rotate_tuple_type result = rotate_tuple<3>()(t); //(b, apple, 6, 1.5, !, 8, house, 3.14)
}
```

Anyways, I want to carry out something to the effect of
    self_compose<10>(rotate_tuple<3>())(t);
(without using the short-cut of changing 3 to 30).  Can someone help here?  The example found at [function composition in C++ / C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071268/function-composition-in-c-c11) doesn't quite work here because it is actually not the same function being reused.  The deduced template value T for rotate_tuple<3>() keeps changing (because the resulting tuple type keeps changing), and hence we don't actually have self composition.  So I guess self_compose is not a good name, say self_repeat.  Anyways, any idea on how to write self_repeat (generic solution that is not specific to rotate_tuple)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename Functor> struct self_composeN
{
    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto operator () (T t) const -> Return((self_composeN<N - 1, Functor>()(Functor()(t))))
};

template <typename Functor> struct self_composeN<0u, Functor>
{
    template <typename T>
    constexpr T operator () (T t) const { return t; }
};
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/PiZwLY).

Comment: Such a simple solution I shouldn't have missed.  Thanks.